# How to use a Multiple SELECT query using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I am looking to select multiple items in my DB based on the primary key.

so if I have the name I want to select imagename and refName from the DB.

I found something here http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = em.createQuery(
      "SELECT c.name, c.capital.name FROM Country AS c", Object[].class);
  List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
  for (Object[] result : results) {
      System.out.println("Country: " + result[0] + ", Capital: " + result[1]);
  }
```

Which doesn't work, and someone else seemed to think the code was awfully wrong so I am curious how exactly I will do this?

Thanks all!

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a parameter value using a name of i.name that does not exist in the query string SELECT i.name, i.refName, i.imageName FROM Items AS i.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.setParameterInternal(QueryImpl.java:928)  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.setParameterInternal(QueryImpl.java:928)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:593)
    at uploader.AdminControl.fileCreate(AdminControl.java:745)
    at uploader.AdminControl.upload(AdminControl.java:660)
    ... 57 more
```

..

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> q = em2.createQuery("SELECT i.name, i.refName, i.imageName FROM Items AS i",Object[].class);
q.setParameter("name", plan.getFace()[i].name);
System.out.println(q);


                            List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();

                            for (Object[] result : results)
                            {
                            bw.write(result[1].toString());
                            bw.write(result[2].toString());
                            System.out.println("result:" + result[1].toString() + "and" + result[2].toString());
                            }
```

Comment: So why doesn't your query mention `refName`, and if this is supposed to be based on the name ("if I have the name") why isn't there a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: This is the example from the link above... sorry.

I was just showing this is what I was given, is this correct to use?

updated to show error.

Comment: Give us real code. Looks like you try to get name from Items class POJO. Items sounds like multiple items...

Comment: Yes it exists, and this code works

 //      Query q = em2.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Items i WHERE i.name = :name");
               // q.setParameter(name", plan.getFace()[i].name);
               // System.out.println("Total Points: " + q.getResultList());

Yes, it's an entity class called Items, that connects to information to my DB.......

yes there are multiple items within the table Items.....

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with q.setParameter("i.name", plan.getFace()[i].name); ?

Comment: actually it should have been just "name" the other was a test..

Anyways from the objectdb site they would do the queries without the paramater, but with the parameter it seems I can select 1 entry in my table.

I am looking for the method in which to use my name to select the others but then grab the data for that one name aka lets say Bob.  From entry Bob of name I get the refName and imageName associated with Bob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of this code:

```
q.setParameter("i.name", plan.getFace()[i].name);
```

Take a look at your JPQL:

```
SELECT i.name, i.refName, i.imageName FROM Items AS i
```

You have no parameter named `i.name`. You should create one that will receive the parameter. Something like

```
    SELECT i.name, i.refName, i.imageName FROM Items AS i where i.name = :parameterName
```

And do pass the value:

```
q.setParameter("parameterName", plan.getFace()[i].name);
```

Comment: As I mentioned above I accidentally had the parameter with the "i." in front because I figured "WHY NOT" :).
This

 SELECT i.name, i.refName, i.imageName FROM Items AS i where i.name = :parameterName

ended up working for my needs.  I was trying to use a regular SELECT statement and figure out the rest, but I was a bit confused as to where I needed to put what, but this makes sense, so thank you very much@!@@

Answer (score 0):

The problem is param name

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> q = em2.createQuery("SELECT i.name, i.refName, i.imageName FROM Items WHERE i.name = :someparam AS i",Object[].class);
q.setParameter("someparam", plan.getFace()[i].name);
```

Comment: As I mentioned above I accidentally had the parameter set with the "i." in front because I figured "WHY NOT" :). 

this WAS NOT the error.